# How to arrange the nodes according to class in ggraph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

everyone. I used ggraph to draw a circular layout plot. And I want to arrange node according to their class, I mean all the nodes in the same class are placed one by one in the circular layout? Any ideas is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you could pose your question in such a way that others can recreate it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/12400385) are some tips on how to create a reproducible example.

Comment: You'll need to include 1: code and some example data that can be used to illustrate your problem, and 2. a picture of your current result or one that can help us understand what you are looking to do.  I believe from your question we can certainly help you, but it will not be received without a bit more information here.